# How to save panels position in wx.aui

Tags: python, wxwidgets

How can i save the position of my wx.aui panels in *.ini file (for examples)? Methods GetPosition() and GetSize() give me only the defaultsizes and positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use wx.aui.AuiManager.SavePerspective and wx.aui.AuiManager.LoadPerspective to load and save layout data (assuming you have a consistent set of panes when you load as you had when you saved)

For wxPython SavePerspective will just return a string which you can store somewhere and then pass into LoadPerspective. This may not work 100% reliably - I've had a number of problems with it before.

Documentation for wxWidgets is here:
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxauimanager.html#wxauimanagersaveperspective
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxauimanager.html#wxauimanagerloadperspective

For a single pane in a manager, you can use SavePaneInfo and LoadPaneInfo on the wx.aui.AuiManager

Comment: i know about this methods but if i want to save my panel positions to my computer, and load them after restart my program?

Comment: If you want to load them after you restart the program, save them somehow to a file - e.g. just writing the text out to a file, using wx.Config or using ConfigParser.RawConfigParser to write to an ini file/registry. Then on startup, once you have created your AUI manager + panes, check for the presence of the file, read it and load the perspective.

Comment: thank you. i understand. i had some problems with encoding but i solved them